# Password cannot be provided because the user is not authenticated in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am developing an application which should have to create on database server new database new login and new user as owner of this new one. This is for automatization for deploying of web application.

this is my method:

```
public void CreateDatabase(string connectionString, string newDbName, string newDbUserName, string newDbUserPassword)
{
 var connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

            Server server = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(connection.UserID)
                ? new Server(new ServerConnection(connection.DataSource, connection.UserID, connection.Password))
                : new Server(new ServerConnection(connection.DataSource));

            Login login = null;
            User user = null;
            Database db = null;

                db = new Database(server, newDbName);
                db.Create();

                login = new Login(server, newDbUserName) { LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin };
                login.Create(newDbUserPassword, LoginCreateOptions.None);

                user = new User(db, newDbUserName)
                {
                    UserType = UserType.NoLogin,
                    Login = login.Name, DefaultSchema = "dbo"
                };
                user.Create(newDbUserPassword);

                dbUser.AddToRole("dbcreator");
}
```

The username is generated string without numbers and special chars. Password is generated as 30 chars string with special chars and number.

The trouble is that in my localhost even in server this code throw me this exception:

```
A password cannot be provided because the user is not authenticated in the database.
```

The goal is, new user has access only to this new database

Has someany any idea why and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, i am using an existing user, but not SA.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Is this SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2019